# Angular fullcalendar adding an event when clicking on the day

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Hi hope you will help me on this

I'm working on Angular 10 and full calendar v5 and I want to know how can I add an event into the day when clicking on it

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit{

  nomaction;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }


calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: true,
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
    events: [
      { title: 'event 1', date: '2020-08-20' },
      { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-08-21' }
    ]
  };

  handleDateClick(arg) {
  
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddeventComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {nomaction: this.nomaction}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.nomaction = result.nomaction;
      this.calendarOptions.events = [{ title: this.nomaction, date: arg.dateStr }];//a code for adding an event into the day
      console.log('action',this.nomaction);
    });

   
  }

  toggleWeekends() {
    this.calendarOptions.weekends = !this.calendarOptions.weekends 
     }

 }
```

this.calendarOptions.events is not an array so I couldn't use push to add the object !

How can I add it without losing my first data !

Comment: You need to use the correct function to add an event into the calendar: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent

Comment: thank you for answering me , I found that : calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] ) but I didn't find the type of  calendar , do you know how can I instantiate it ?

Comment: It's in the documentation already - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular under the section "Calendar API"

Comment: Property 'addEvent' does not exist on type 'FullCalendarComponent'.

47       this.calendarComponent.addEvent( { title: this.nomaction, date: arg.dateStr } )

Comment: @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;

Comment: I had this error unfortunetly do you know what 's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is you didn't follow the instructions correctly. You have to call the method on the object returned by the getApi() method, not on the component - this is made clear when it says _you can get the underlying Calendar object via the getApi method:_ .So, per the example in the docs: `let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    calendarApi.next();` - in your case, you'd substitute "next()" for your "addEvent" method. Fullcalendar is a regular JS library, so it's that object you need. The Angular component is just a wrapper round it to make it easier to use in Angular apps.

Comment: it's working now thank you very much , and sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 1):

Add on your calendar options this :

```js
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: true,
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
    events: [
      { title: 'event 1', date: '2020-08-20' },
      { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-08-21' }
    ],
    dateClick:function (info) {
        console.log("See day infos: ",info);
    }
  };
```

I let you the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick)  here